# Getting provider token for APN in PHP

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I have tried different libraries, but they either give me a token that is invalid, or throw error before creating it.
Do you have a working example?

Here are two of my attempts:

composer.json:

```
"edamov/pushok": "^0.11.2",
"lcobucci/jwt": "^3.3"
```

PHP:

```
use Pushok\AuthProvider;

$device_token = "oVVEyzOm8LYn1nEYQLUcp1nBQw+UKHUeJbVHxcqr3ls=";
$keyfile = "AuthKey_ABCDEFGHIJ.p8";
$kid="ABCDEFGHIJ";
$iss="KLMNOPQRST";
$bundleid="myapp.id";

$options = [
    'key_id' => $kid, // The Key ID obtained from Apple developer account
    'team_id' => $iss, // The Team ID obtained from Apple developer account
    'app_bundle_id' => $bundleid, // The bundle ID for app obtained from Apple developer account
    'private_key_path' => $keyfile, // Path to private key
    'private_key_secret' => null
];

$authProvider = AuthProvider\Token::create($options);
$jwt=$authProvider->get();

makeRequest($jwt, $device_token, $bundleid);
```

Output: {"reason":"InvalidProviderToken"} ... int(403)

```
use Lcobucci\JWT\Builder;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Rsa\Sha256;

$signer = new Sha256();
$privateKey = new Key(file_get_contents($keyfile));

$jwt = (new Builder())
->issuedBy($iss) // (iss claim) // teamId
->issuedAt(time()) // time the token was issuedAt
->withHeader('kid', $kid)
->withHeader('alg', 'ES256')
->getToken($signer,  $privateKey);
```

Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: This key is not compatible with this signer in /srv/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Signer/OpenSSL.php:98

```
-------------------------------------------------

function makeRequest($jwt, $device_token, $bundleid) {
    $sample_alert = '{"aps":{"alert":"hello"}}';
    $url = "https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/".urlencode($device_token);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sample_alert);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json", "authorization: bearer ".$jwt, "apns-expiration: 0", "apns-priority: 10", "apns-topic: ".$bundleid));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    var_dump($jwt);
    var_dump($response);
    var_dump($httpcode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. There were two mistakes I had made.

First, I was using a non-existing key - check your Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles page.

Second, the device token was not in the correct form - you can recognize it by the = in the end, the + in the middle, and the length of it was not 64 characters as it should be.

In my RegisteredForRemoteNotifications() function (Xamarin.iOS) I had used the

```
deviceToken.GetBase64EncodedString(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None)
```

function to get the token in string form.
But the correct procedure is

```
byte[] bytes = deviceToken.ToArray<byte>();
string[] hexArray = bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")).ToArray();
string tokenString = string.Join(string.Empty, hexArray);
```